# Deploying custom fxcop rules amongst developers

Tags: windows, group-policy

I am currently in the process of writing and deploying custom FxCop (Visual Studio Code Analysis) rules, allowing developers to check their code against a series of these custom designed rules.

As a part of this I want every developers' computer to check for new .dll files inside a specific (network)location and copy the files into the correct folder; on start-up, that is.

I have written a program that does the execution, but it will not run because it requires to be executed as administrator (copying to a location in Program Files).

Is there any way to distribute these files and have the developers' computers check for newer versions on startup? Say through group policies or another mechanism. My aim is to be as less dependent of my companies System Management as possible, lines are very long; so being able to do this with my own program would be the best solution here.

Comment: I have the same requirement. Did you find anything useful?

Comment: @SaeedNeamati: We just went with asking the developers to execute the program which places the dlls in their correct folders. No automative solution found yet.

Comment: thanks for sharing your experience. I guess we have to go with the same approach too.

Comment: @SaeedNeamati: If you do find a way to automate this process, do share! ;)